# "Implement me. Unknown stdin file type!" error with flickrapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I am using the [flickrapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flickrapi) for NodeJS and keep running into the error listed in the title.

Everything works fine on my local machine (OSX 10.10.1), but Azure chokes every time. The app runs, but anything that uses the flickrapi chokes. Example below:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Flickr = require("flickrapi"),
    flickrOptions = {
        api_key: '**********',
        secret: '***********'
    };

router.get('/galleries', function(req, res) {
    Flickr.tokenOnly(flickrOptions, function(error, flickr) {
        var albums = [];
        flickr.photosets.getList({ user_id: '*********' }, function(err, result) {
            result.photosets.photoset.forEach(function(set){
                albums.push(new Album(set));
            });

            albums.forEach(function(album, index, array) {
                flickr.photosets.getPhotos({ photoset_id: album.id }, function(err, pResult) { 
                    addPhotosToAlbum(pResult.photoset.photo, album, function() {
                        if (index === array.length - 1) {
                            res.json({ albums: albums });
                         }
                    });
                });
            })
        });
    });
});

function Album(photoset) {
    this.id = photoset.id;
    this.title = photoset.title._content;
    this.photos = [];
}

function Photo(photo) {
    this.url = new URL(photo);
}

function URL(photo) {
    var url = 'http://farm' + photo.farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + photo.server + '/';
    url += photo.id + '_' + photo.secret + '_';

    this.thumbnail = url + 't.jpg';
    this.small = url + 'm.jpg';
    this.medium = url + 'z.jpg';
    this.large = url + 'k.jpg';
}

function addPhotosToAlbum(photos, album, finish) {
    photos.forEach(function(photo, index, array) {
        album.photos.push(new Photo(photo));
        if (index === array.length - 1) {
            finish();
        }
    });

}

module.exports = router;
```

## Update 1

I removed everything but the initial query, even that throws an error:

```
router.get('/galleries', function(req, res) {
    Flickr.tokenOnly(flickrOptions, function(error, flickr) {
        flickr.photosets.getList({ user_id: '*********' }, function(err, result) {
            res.json({ albums: result });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I've just come across this error on a Windows 7 machine trying to use BrowserStackLocal.exe. Pity no one knows why!